# Rank - without gaps for every partition in Teradata

Tags: teradata, rank, row-number

I have 30 columns, of which based on every distinct `VEHICLE_ABBR`, `BLOCK_NO` poulate `Trip` column based on Incresing order of `DEPARTURE_TIME` .

```
VEHICLE_ABBR BLOCK_NO   DEPARTURE_TIME  Trip
SXXB1410D   21,760,010  19,500           1
SXXB1410D   21,760,010  24,900           2
SXXB1410D   21,760,010  31,020           3
TXXB1102R   21,760,026  19,800           1
TXXB1102R   21,760,026  24,480           2
MXXB1410P   21,760,011  17,500           1
MXXB1410P   21,760,011  19,900           2
JXXB1102K   21,760,027  20,800           1
JXXB1102K   21,760,027  22,480           2
JXXB1102K   21,760,027  23,480           3


SELECT

   BLOCK_NO

    ,VEHICLE_ABBR

    ,DEPARTURE_TIME

,SUM(CASE WHEN TRIP = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   

OVER (PARTITION BY BLOCK_NO,VEHICLE_ABBR  ORDER BY DEPARTURE_TIME, TRIP ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS TRIP_NUM

FROM
     (
      SELECT
        BLOCK_NO
        ,VEHICLE_ABBR
        ,DEPARTURE_TIME

    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BLOCK_NO,VEHICLE_ABBR,DEPARTURE_TIME ORDER BY DEPARTURE_TIME ) AS TRIP

  FROM tab

 ) AS dt;
```

Comment: What's your Teradata release? TD14.10 supports `DENSE_RANK`, before you need nested OLAP functions. But you example data looks like a simple `RANK`

Comment: @dnoeth Teradata release version is TD13

Comment: Wow, that's an ancient release. See http://developer.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/05/missing-functions-dense-rank

Comment: @dnoeth i tried the suggestion, but i get rank with gaps(missing numbers)

Comment: Can you add some more data and your current query?

Comment: @dnoeth updated the question

Comment: Your code returns exactly what you described, a DENSE_RANK without gaps (of course, based on your data it's a RANK). Maybe add more data showing duplicate values for `VEHICLE_ABBR,BLOCK_NO,DEPARTURE_TIME`

Comment: @dnoeth I get different result everytime i run

Comment: This usually means you order by something not unique, but this query includes the ROW_NUMBER and thus it **is** unique.